# Combined legend entry for plot and fill_between

Tags: matplotlib, legend

This is similar to [Matlab: Combine the legends of shaded error and solid line mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617190/matlab-combine-the-legends-of-shaded-error-and-solid-line-mean), except for Matplotlib. Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0,1])
y = x + 1
f,a = plt.subplots()
a.fill_between(x,y+0.5,y-0.5,alpha=0.5,color='b')
a.plot(x,y,color='b',label='Stuff',linewidth=3)
a.legend()

plt.show()
```

The above code produces a legend that looks like this:

[image]

How can I create a legend entry that combines the shading from `fill_between` and the line from `plot`, so that it looks something like this (mockup made in Gimp):

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

MPL supports tuple inputs to legend so that you can create composite legend entries (see the last figure on [this](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/legend_guide.html#legend-handler) page). However, as of now PolyCollections--which fill_between creates/returns--are not supported by legend, so simply supplying a PolyCollection as an entry in a tuple to legend won't work ([a fix is anticipated for mpl 1.5.x](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3303)).

Until the fix arrives I would recommend using a [proxy artist](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists) in conjunction with the 'tuple' legend entry functionality. You could use the `mpl.patches.Patch` interface (as demonstrated on the proxy artist page) or you could just use fill. e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0, 1])
y = x + 1
f, a = plt.subplots()
a.fill_between(x, y + 0.5, y - 0.5, alpha=0.5, color='b')
p1 = a.plot(x, y, color='b', linewidth=3)
p2 = a.fill(np.NaN, np.NaN, 'b', alpha=0.5)
a.legend([(p2[0], p1[0]), ], ['Stuff'])

plt.show()
```

[image: Compound legend with fill_between]

Comment: Thanks! Adding `linewidth=0` to the `fill` makes this good enough, that removes the 'frame' from the legend entry. If you happen to know how to make the legend keys the same length, so the line from `plot` extends to the left/right edges of the `fill` rectangle in the legend, that would be even better.