# Is it possible to iteratively build up legend entries through multiple plot function calls?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Based on the question and answer here ([Line plus shaded region for error band in matplotlib's legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736920/line-plus-shaded-region-for-error-band-in-matplotlibs-legend;) and similar to [Combined legend entry for plot and fill_between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217687/combined-legend-entry-for-plot-and-fill-between)) I was able to create a legend entry which combines a line and patch elements.

In my use-case I need to plot multiple of these. When I do, I only get a legend entry for the last line+patch combination.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot(x, y, ax, col, group, **kwargs):
    hline, = ax.plot(x, y, 'k--', color=col)
    hpatch = ax.fill_between(x, y+10, y-10, color=col, alpha=0.5)
    ax.legend([(hline, hpatch)], [f"group {group}: Mean + interval"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
plot(x, x, ax, "C0", 1)
plot(x, x+30, ax, "C1", 2)
plot(x, x+60, ax, "C2", 3)
```

[image]

Note the presence of only the final (group 3) entry in the legend.

Is there a way to get all line/path groups included in the legend so that (in this case) there are 3 items in the legend?

Bonus points if this can be handled entirely within the `plot` function, avoiding having to pass out handles from the plot function.

This question is not asking about multiple separate legends.

Comment: The problem is that overriding the ax. legend when u call the plot method, that's why u get the legend of the last plot.

Answer (score 3):

For something to appear in the legend, matplotlib uses the `label=` keyword.
You can use `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` to find all the elements that have a label.  Recombining these handles and labels can create your desired legend.  Calling `ax.legend` multiple times will erase the old legend and set a new one.

The test code replaces `ax.plot(x, y, 'k--', ...` by `ax.plot(x, y, '--', ...`. Note that here `k` would color the line black, but the color is already set by the `color=` keyword.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot(x, y, ax, col, group, **kwargs):
    ax.plot(x, y, '--', color=col, label=f"group {group}: Mean")
    ax.fill_between(x, y + 10, y - 10, color=col, alpha=0.5, label='interval')
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    print(handles, labels)
    ax.legend(handles=[(h1, h2) for h1, h2 in zip(handles[::2], handles[1::2])],
              labels=[l1 + " + " +l2 for l1, l2 in zip(labels[::2], labels[1::2])])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
plot(x, x, ax, "C0", 1)
plot(x, x + 30, ax, "C1", 2)
plot(x, x + 60, ax, "C2", 3)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot with extending the legend]

Comment: This is a good solution. Only minor quibble is that if there are other elements plotted on the figure then the indexing in the handles and labels breaks.

Comment: Normally, you can access the existing legend entries via `ax.legend_.legendHandles` but that doesn't seem to work with the tupples you're using.

Comment: There's a question here about that https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/retrieving-handles-from-legend-returns-line-and-not-tuple/23422/1

Comment: If your figure is more complicated, then you need to track the handles and labels manually by creating the list as you create the artists.

Answer (score 2):

You could return the combined artist and the label from the plot-function and use those to create the legend at the end.

```py
def plot(x, y, ax, col, group, **kwargs):
    hline, = ax.plot(x, y, 'k--', color=col)
    hpatch = ax.fill_between(x, y+10, y-10, color=col, alpha=0.5)
    return (hline, hpatch), f"group {group}: Mean + interval"

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)

l1 = plot(x, x, ax, "C0", 1)
l2 = plot(x, x+30, ax, "C1", 2)
l3 = plot(x, x+60, ax, "C2", 3)

ax.legend(*zip(*[l1,l2,l3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following, thinking it would work

```py
def plot(x, y, ax, col, group, **kwargs):  
    legend = ax.get_legend() or []
    if legend:
        handles = legend.legendHandles
        labels = [txt.get_text() for txt in legend.get_texts()]
    else:
        handles = []
        labels = []
    hline, = ax.plot(x, y, ls='--', color=col)
    hpatch = ax.fill_between(x, y+10, y-10, color=col, alpha=0.5)
    
    handles += [(hline, hpatch)]
    labels += [f"group {group}: Mean + interval"]

    ax.legend(handles, labels)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
x = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
plot(x, x, ax, "C0", 1)
plot(x, x + 30, ax, "C1", 2)
plot(x, x + 60, ax, "C2", 3)
```

However, I get this

[image]

If we have a look at the handles, it looks like it only shows the lines

```py
ax.get_legend().legendHandles
```

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f066b54b370>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f066b54b940>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f066b54bdc0>]
```

I was trying to see if this is a bug or intended behavior.

I also tried

```py
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

def plot(x, y, ax, col, group, **kwargs):  
    legend = ax.get_legend() or []
    if legend:
        handles = legend.legendHandles
        labels = [txt.get_text() for txt in legend.get_texts()]
    else:
        handles = []
        labels = []
    hline, = ax.plot(x, y, ls='--', color=col)
    hpatch = ax.fill_between(x, y+10, y-10, color=col, alpha=0.5)
    label = f"group {group}: Mean + interval"
    handle = (Line2D([], [], color=col, label=label), Patch(color=col, alpha=0.5, label=label))
    handles += [handle]
    labels += [label]

    ax.legend(handles, labels)
```

but the result is still the same